# How to render nodes sharing same trigger?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

My use case is kind of what I have simplified in below example. How to render components sharing same trigger?

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        let dropDownItem = <DropDown.Item> An Item! </DropDown.Item> 

        let modal = <Modal trigger={dropDownItem}></Modal>

        let popup = <Popup trigger={dropDownItem}></Popup>

        return(
                  <DropDown.Menu>
                        {modal} or {popup} 
                  // How to share same trigger among multiple components.
                  <DropDown.Menu>
              )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can place one inside the other.  In this instance, it would be

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

render() {
    let dropDownItem = <DropDown.Item> An Item! </DropDown.Item> 

    let modal = <Modal trigger={dropDownItem}></Modal>

    let popup = <Popup trigger={modal}></Popup>

    return(
              <DropDown.Menu>
                {popup} 
              <DropDown.Menu>
          )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to let Modal not use a trigger, but rather control it's visibility using Modal's `open` property:

```
<Modal open={this.state.isOpen}>Content</Modal>
```

On clicking the dropdown item, you'd set `this.state.isOpen = true` and the modal would be shown.